# Erro ao adicionar migração com Migrations

Tags: entity-framework-6

Estou tentando adicionar uma migração e o migration retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration AddedStoredProc' again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tudo bem. Esta mensagem quer dizer:

> O código em modo **designer** para esta migração inclui um *snapshop* (fotografia) do seu modelo em *Code First* (o conjunto de *Models* aqui, no caso). Esta fotografia é usada para calcular as mudanças no seu modelo (novamente, o conjunto), quando você pré-moldar a próxima migração. Se você fizer mudanças adicionais em seu modelo (mais uma vez, o conjunto de *Models*) que você gostaria de incluir nesta migração, você pode pré-moldar a migração novamente usando o comando 'Add-Migration AddedStoredProc' novamente.

É apenas uma orientação do que fazer se algo for alterado antes de você executar um `Update-Database`.

Comment: Obrigada Cigano!